# Нужна ли здесь запятая и почему?

Tags: пунктуация

"Отзыв из отпуска возможен не ранее(,) чем работник "отгуляет" положенную норму".
Когда в таких случаях запятая ставится, а когда нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь запятая нужна, поскольку это сложное предложение, а вот насчет кавычек я, признаться, сомневаюсь.